# HighChart accessibility glitch?

Tags: highcharts, accessibility

I  have followed the accessibility example for a Highchart stock chart demo and noticed that sometimes I could access the data points using the arrow keys, and sometimes I cannot.

It turns out when I do not have NVDA running, I can access the data points with the arrow keys, and when NVDA is running, I cannot.  I am using the latest version of Highchart's accessibility JS file (version 8.2.2)

I have also noticed this occurs on the [demo chart](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/stock/accessibility/accessible-stock).   Has anyone come across this too and have a workaround solution to share?

Comment: Hi @RPC, Screen readers generally highjack the keyboard navigation, so when NVDA is running, Highcharts' keyboard commands will not work. You should still be able to access the data points using NVDA's reading commands, by browsing through the chart - is this working?

Comment: Please note that there is an issue with NVDA active because it has screen layout enabled by default, this is an issue with NVDA and is logged with them: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12151

Comment: @ppotaczek thanks for the information.  When I let NVDA read the page, when it comes to the chart, NVDA will describe an overview of it, which includes a summary, the X and Y axis, how many data points there are, the time range options, the to and from dates.

When  using the tab key, I can access the time range options, the to and from dates, and sometimes the top-right menu.  If this is what you mean by browsing through the chart, than yes it is working.